# Is there a Hand tool avaliable like in photoshop?

Tags: export, 3d-cursor

1. Is there any Hand tool available for blender like moving entire world (I'm not asking about the middle mouse click movement. I'm asking like entire world movement like Hand tool in Photoshop & other Software)

2.How can I export .obj files with changed pivot position using blender? Every time pivot gets reset to the default position.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to BSE. Please ask two separate questions and give them two separate titles, so it may be helpful for people who'll be searching for the similar problem as yours in future.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and keep only the first question. The second one please ask it on a new post.

Answer (score 3):

The "Hand tool" is made by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd>.
To export select the mesh, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>S</kbd> *Cursor to Center*, select your mesh, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+ <kbd>S</kbd> *Selection to Cursor*, then export.

In this way, when you export the object it will have his origin exactly in the center of the scene, which is where the export .obj function places the pivot point.

Comment: Thank you. I got answer for my first question. And I know how to change/re-position 3D cursor and everything in a mesh. but I was asking that I can't export the cursor with that re-positioned place. like for example. I've a sword model (obj file) I imported it to blender and the pivot point shown in the middle of the sword. I changed it's position into handle of the sword and exported it. If I import the edited model. Then It's pivot point again reset to the old position. what can I do?

Comment: Edited the answer